# iframe I have a problem with cross-origin

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I would need to insert a site in an iframe which requests access to the computer camera

```
<iframe src="https://url" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" allow="microphone; camera"></iframe>
```

But, Chrome return "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://urlxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

I don't change anything on the remote page

How to do ?

Thanks